# Elements in Array1 that are equal to or less than elements in array2?

Tags: javascript

Scenario:
If given an Array1, such as `[1, 2, 3]`, and Array2 `[2,4]`, I need the output to be `[2, 3]` because there are 2 elements in Array1 that are less than or equal to Array2[1] and 3 elements in `Array1` that are less than or equal to `Array2[2]`.

So far, I've got this...

```js
function counts(nums, maxes) {
  let empArr = [];
  //compare SECOND ARRAY maxes
  for (let i = 0, count = 0; i < maxes.length; i++) {
    //to FIRST ARRAY nums
    for (let j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
      if (nums[j] <= maxes[i]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    empArr.push(count);
  }
  return empArr
}

console.log(counts([1, 2, 3], [2, 3]));
```

This gives me `[2, 5]` yet I expect `[2, 3]`. Any help here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `count = 0;` declaration within your `for()` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. Declarations of this nature within a `for` constructor are only run once before the first iteration of the loop. Manually reset your `count` at the top of the loop:

```js
function counts(nums, maxes) {
  let empArr = [];
  //compare SECOND ARRAY maxes
  for (let i = 0; i < maxes.length; i++) {
    let count = 0;
    //to FIRST ARRAY nums
    for (let j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
      if (nums[j] <= maxes[i]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    empArr.push(count);
  }
  return empArr
}

console.log(counts([1, 2, 3], [2, 3]));
```

Comment: Yep! That was exactly it, I didn't realize the count inside the loop constructor wasn't happening every time. Thank you!